# concatenate two byteBuffers to a single

Tags: java, concatenation, bytebuffer

Hi I've 2 byteBuffers and I want to concatenate them together to a single byteBuffer.
I found a similar question here but none of the suggestions there worked for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
    ByteBuffer b3 = ByteBuffer.allocate(b1.limit() + b2.limit());
    b3.put(b1);
    b3.put(b2);
```

Comment: You can add that you should `rewind` the resulting ByteBuffer before reading from it.  FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48257336/java-crc32-update-on-concatenated-bytebuffer