# Java - CRC32.update() on concatenated ByteBuffer

Tags: java, byte, bytebuffer, crc32

I have the following function:

```
   byte[] test1 = {1,2,3,4};
   byte[] test2 = {5,6,7,8};
   ByteBuffer bbtest1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(test1).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
   ByteBuffer bbtest2= ByteBuffer.wrap(test2).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

   ByteBuffer contents = ByteBuffer.allocate(bbtest1.limit() + bbtest2.limit());
   contents.put(bbtest1);
   contents.put(bbtest2);

   CRC32 checksum = new CRC32();
   checksum.update(contents);

   System.out.println(checksum.getValue());
```

No matter what values I assign my byte arrays, getValue() always returns 0 when I have concatenated by byteBuffers. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734268/concatenate-two-bytebuffers-to-a-single/30734513#30734513), this is a valid way of concatenating byteBuffers. If I only call put() on a single byteBuffer (for example if I comment out the line `byte[] test2 = {5,6,7,8};` then getValue() actually returns a valid value.

Is this an issue with the way the ByteBuffers are concatenated, update(ByteBuffer) performs on concatenated ByteBuffers, or maybe something else altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calls to `put` have advanced the position of the ByteBuffer to the point that there is no byte left to read from it for `CRC32.update()`.

If you only put one of the two byte buffers, then there will still be 4 bytes to read for the CRC checksum (all 4 have the value 0).

You need to reset the position of your bytebuffer to zero before calling `checksum.update(contents)`. You can use `rewind` or `flip` for that:

```
contents.rewind();
```

or

```
contents.flip();
```

Flip does the same as `rewind()`, but additionally it sets the `limit` of the ByteBuffer to the `position` it had before flipping, so if you first constructed the content of the ByteBuffer and then want to read from it, `flip()` is more correct, as you don't run the risk of reading from parts of the ByteBuffer that you didn't yet write into.

EJP's answer is insightful, as he points out that you don't need to concatenate byte buffers at all.

You can alternatively do one of:

- update the CRC32 with the individual ByteBuffers
- use `ByteBuffer.put(byte[])` to directly put the `test1` and `test2` byte arrays in the `contents` ByteBuffer
- skip ByteBuffers altogether and call `CRC32.update(byte[])` with `test1` and `test2` in sequence.

Comment: `rewind()` works but `flip()` is semantically more correct. `rewind()` is for re-reading.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, you’re right. I’ll update when I get back behind non-mobile device

Answer (score 2):

You need to prepare the buffer for getting (or writing to a channel) by calling `flip()` after the puts (or reads from a channel), and `compact()` it afterwards.

But I don't know why you're concatenating `ByteBuffers` at all. Just do

```
checksum.update(bbtest1);
checksum.update(bbtest2);
```

There's no advantage to creating yet another copy of the data, and NIO contains scatter/gather methods to operate on multiple `ByteBuffers` at once.